# (REOPENED) Request to reopen the question on employees gaming a reward points system

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

This question ([How can I prevent my employees from gaming a reward points system?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/89507/3192)) was closed as off-topic because in its original version, it seemed to ask for an app design.

The OP clarified in the comments and edits that their actual issue was about preventing the cashier from gaming the system, which seems to be on-topic.

I have edited the question to remove the details of the app features and rules, in order to focus on the main on-topic issue.

Please consider casting reopen votes if you agree.

Comment: Voted to re-open

Comment: This question as it is now is fine.  VTO

Comment: Why would app design be on topic here?

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings I see no reason why. That was also my custom close reason on the question.

Comment: @MaskedMan because the scope of this site is navigating the workplace but expressly limited to not performing job functions.  This is about app design not navigating the workplace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that was fast! The question has been reopened now. Thanks, Workplace community!

Comment: I wanted to accept this answer to indicate that the request has been resolved, but [some dude made a rule ages ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6045/202356) preventing that to avoid ... you guessed it ... "gaming the system".